# Adding whitespace only at the bottom of an image with ImageMagick (-geometry)

Tags: imagemagick

I've been doing something like this to add a text label to an image using ImageMagick

```
montage -label "label" -pointsize 36 img.png -geometry 'x1000>' out.png
```

I use the resize option of `-geometry` (`x1000>`) because otherwise the label is too close to the image.
What I actually want is to only add whitespace at the *bottom* of the image, so as to place the label there. I would also like for the label to not be next to the edge of the image, but centered in the newly created whitespace region. Is this possible? Here's a small sketch to hopefully make this clearer:

I currently have:

```
 ------------
| whitespace |
|   image    |
| whitespace |
|   label    |
 ------------
```

What I actually want is something like:

```
 ------------ 
|   image    |
| whitespace |
|   label    |
| whitespace |
 ------------
```

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling around, I found the following workaround using `convert`

```
convert -frame 0x50 -mattecolor White -gravity South -annotate +0+25 "label" img.png out.png
```

This still pads the top, but at least now it gives me the option to place the text where I want it. I had to use `-frame` instead of resizing with `geometry` because, for some reason, trying to add the text in the region added by `-geometry` wouldn't work. Adding the text a couple of pixels above the newly created region would cut off the text at the point where the new region started.

Comment: I was going to say you should use `convert` and `-gravity`. So hey! My only suggestion to make this question and answer post more solid would be to actually add some real image examples. Your ASCII layouts work to a degree, gut still: This is about images so best use them when you can.